# Need Help With Storyboard to Mimic the Way IPhone Flips Album Art

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

Trying to mimic the way the IPhone flips the album art to the songs list.  I want to pass in two generic objects and have the storyboard flip them.  I can get the slide effect, but have not figured out how to scale the object so it appears to be rotating and not just sliding.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

It would be more work to do it in XAML than to use one of the existing components. Anyway, if you look at doing this in XAML, you need to use [Viewport2dVisual3d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.aspx) class. 
Otherwise, here are some links to get you going (personally, I'm using the FluidKit).

[FluidKit](http://www.codeplex.com/fluidkit)

[Is there a good iTunes coverflow-type control for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163775/is-there-a-good-itunes-coverflow-type-control-for-wpf)

[Transitionals project](http://www.codeplex.com/transitionals)

[Kevin's WPF Bag-o-Tricks](http://j832.com/bagotricks/)

[Flippable 3D List Items in WPF](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list)