# Custom scroll layout with fisheye in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, popup, custom-controls, fisheye

I know Windows Forms quite good but I'm new to WPF.

I'd like to create application similar to RSS reader - in main window every note will be displayed in Post-it like frame and all notes should be chained and scrollable up and down. I also want to include kind of fisheye view - single note will be displayed full size in the centre of the screen and will shrink and rotate on the edge.

I know custom control, transformation and databinding concepts but I'm not sure how to handle displaying and scrolling notes in the main window. The questions are:

- what is the suggested way to arrange, display and scroll ordered chain of notes?
- should single note discover own position on the screen or it should be notified by it's container?
- how in such solution provide feature which will open related notes as a "multiple popups" notes connected by a line with original one? (like traversing correlated results in Google Wonder Wheel, adobe flash there)
- are there any standard solutions for displaying and manipulating (moving, attaching, collapsing) such popup-widgets?

If there are any similarities in your proposal to other GUI frameworks (Forms, Swing, SWT), comparison are welcome too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are describing a "carousel control" or "element flow" or "cover flow". I've put some links at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986271/need-help-with-storyboard-to-mimic-the-way-iphone-flips-album-art/988246#988246).