# how to make Cover Flow in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have seen Cover Flow effect using WPF, and I'm looking for a tutorial. Where I can find the tutorial?

Comment: If you couldn't find it, you didn't search for it: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wpf+coverflow+tutorial&oq=WPF+CoverFlow+tutor&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=8696l9783l0l10566l6l5l0l3l3l0l219l318l1.0.1l2l0

Comment: already, but I'm still can't find it

Comment: There's also this (possibly duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163775/is-there-a-good-itunes-coverflow-type-control-for-wpf (which I just realized is already in Maxim's answer)

Answer (score 2):

[WPF Cover Flow Tutorial](http://d3dal3.blogspot.com/2008/10/wpf-cover-flow-tutorial-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163775/is-there-a-good-itunes-coverflow-type-control-for-wpf) question:

ElementFlow control is inside the codeplex project called [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) should work for you.

It pretty much requires no tutorial to get going.

Comment: I little confused look code FluidKit. I have no idea how to separate only coverflow

Comment: The control is the part for the namespace in FluidKit. You can just use it in your project, not using other controls.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a ready to use [coverflow control](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/coverflow.aspx), which works fine is you're willing to pay for it.